# Timer just works if call MessageBox.Show()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

How is this possible? I have a timer that is called if have no network connection,as in method down:

```
public void Foo() {
     for (int i = 0, count = MailList.CheckedItems.Count; i < count; i++) {
         /* Check for network available connection in computer
              public bool HasConnection() {
                return System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
             }       
         */
         if (!net.HasConnection()) { 
              SearchNetworkConnection.Start(); //start the timer 
         }
     }
}
```

and The `_Tick` method of `Timer`:

```
   private void SearchNetworkConnection_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            ++ATTEMPRECONNECT;

            string currentState = "attemp reconnect.."; 
            MessageBox.Show(currentState, "..", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            if (ATTEMPRECONNECT >= ATTEMPRECONNECTLIMIT) {
                //do abort all process 
                SearchNetworkConnection.Stop();
            }
      }
```

That works oddly, just if I call the `MessageBox.Show()` after `SearchNetworkConnection.Start()`.

In other words, it does not work, the Timer won't run:

```
if (!net.HasConnection()) { 
        SearchNetworkConnection.Start();
   }
```

calling `MessageBox.Show()`, it works fine:

```
if (!net.HasConnection()) { 
        SearchNetworkConnection.Start();
        MessageBox.Show("lol");
 }
```

if it can be useful, `Foo()` method run on thread.

### Update

So, I think it's a little strange. I wrote a simple code for some tests. and I'm surprise,the mistake continue. The below code works fine, but if you do change the order

```
timer.Start();
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(text, caption);
```

to

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(text, caption);
timer.Start();
```

it does not work, the timer does not start.

```
public static DialogResult Show(string text, string caption,int dellay)
        {

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = dellay;
            timer.Start();
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(text, caption);
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate
             {
                    IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, caption);

                    if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        IntPtr hresult = SendMessage(handle, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

                        if (hresult == IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            timer.Stop();
                            timer.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
            });

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Your `Foo` method calls `Timer.Start` even if the timer is already started. Is it possible that calling `Start` resets the time interval? Perhaps you should write `if (!net.HasConnection() && !SearchNetworkConnection.Enabled)`.

Answer (score 4):

Your Timer needs a messagepump to run. MessageBox.Show() is providing one.

But you'll want to avoid messageboxes altogether (look at Systems.Diagnostsics.Debug.Print()).

You should probably take a look at other timers (System.Threading, System.Timers).

---

Part 2

You state that `Foo()` runs on a Thread. That sounds OK.
But the fact that your Windows.Forms.Timer needs a MessageBox to function means that you are somehow blocking your main thread. So your problem is not in the posted code but somewhere else.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: what's "messagepump"? at first I tried using Debug.WriteLine() and so after MessageBox. 
I believe that with .Print() method can't be much different.

Comment: Yeah, you know. `while (GetMessage()) { Dispatchmessage(); }` . Every Windows app has one, usually inside `Application.Run()`.

Comment: @Jack: Yes, a Debug.WriteLine/.Print won't solve your direct problem. Just improve your program.

Comment: Well,I think the timer control looks like best solution for this case instead Thread(althought it works much like).